# SAS - Get line number from code file

Tags: sas

I would like to print the line number (from the SAS program file) when a certain condition occurs. How can I retrieve that value and print it?

I want to do something like this:

```
%put 'An error occurred on line ' &LINE_NO;
```

Comment: I think you'll have a hard time doing this.  Even SAS has a hard time with the idea of line numbering, particularly when a single line of code (e.g. a macro call or call execute) can generate many SAS statements.  The good news is that usually errors are printed in the log pretty close to where they occur.  If you give an example of the sort of code you are submitting and the message you would want, people might be able to help with alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for your response Quentin. I'm creating a simple test framework that will allow me to call an assertion macro. When one of the assertions fails, I want the line number of the assert call to be printed to a log. Do you know of any way to do such a thing? I need to create my own test framework because I'm unable to install any additional libraries into the the secure environment I work in.

Comment: Ugh. Assertions are a favorite topic of mine. (http://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug12/cc/cc31.pdf). I can't think of how to print the line number. Usually I print the asserted condition, and maybe ancillary variables. Can imagine a counter that would count the number of assertions called, so you could print assertion #i or whatever. But line number of the code seems harder. Hopefully someone else will have an idea.

Comment: Very curious about the downvote - while I don't particularly find this question useful to me per se, it's definitely not a bad one.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's a thought.  First write a .sas file with all of your assertions. And each assertion is a macro call, that has a placeholder for the line number. So mycode.sas looks like:

```
data want;
  set have;
  %assert( (x=y), line=_linenumber_)
  %assert( (a<b), line=_linenumber_)
run;
```

Once that is done, you write another SAS program that reads mycode.sas and writes MyCodeWithLineNumbers.sas, which looks like:

```
data want;
  set have;
  %assert( (x=y), line=3)
  %assert( (a<b), line=4)
run;
```

Then you submit MyCodeWithLineNumbers.sas.  It shouldn't be hard to write the program that to read through the .sas file, count the lines, and replace `_linenumber_` with the appropriate value.

Comment: That's genius! I can't believe I didn't think of that. I still wish there was a system defined global variable called _LINE_ that would provide the line number.